# Combing 3 byte/pin values into one byte

Tags: c++, c, binary

I have 4 pin values defined P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, with bit values. (1/0)

I want to combine them into one byte value, example:

0000 0101 (***3 LSB are the pins***)

How can i do this?

Comment: How are `P1_1`, etc. actually defined??

Comment: Have you looked at [`<bitset>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ysebswc.aspx)?

Comment: If there are four values, why are only the “3 LSB … the pins”?  Shouldn't there be four?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
value = (P1_1<<3)|(P1_2<<2)|(P1_3<<1)|(P1_4);
```

Disclaimers: this is pretty ugly example. In your actual code you probably want some kind of constants defined for shift (so you are able to do the reverse operation without using more magic literal values).

Also note that this will have unexpected results if one of P constants is not 0 or 1. In this case one might use something like !!P1_x instead of P1_x.

Answer (score 3):

```
bitset<4> temp;
temp[0] = P1_1;
temp[1] = P1_2;
temp[2] = P1_3;
temp[3] = P1_4;

unsigned char value = static_cast<unsigned char>(temp.to_ulong());
```